# Unable to display API data on React frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I'm trying to return data fetched from a private API and display it on a page. My frontend use React JS and my backend use node with Express and Axion. My code work up to the point of returning the data. I get my APi Key and fetch my data but the data is not transferred to my page (Quotes.js).

Backend
app.js

```js
import express from "express";
import { getCase } from "./getCase.js";

const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("app.js call getCase");
  res.send(getCase());
  //console.log(req);
});

//console.log(Quote.getQuote());

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Backend getCase

```js
import { getToken } from "./nsApiToken.js";
import axios from "axios";

let getData = "";
console.log("begin of getCase");
const getCase = async () => {
  let tokenRes = await getToken();

  const url =
    "https://5156735-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=860&deploy=1&recordtype=supportcase&id=717986";

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenRes.data.access_token}`,
      },
    });
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

export { getCase };
```

Frontend App.js

```jsx
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Quotes from "./Quotes.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Quotes />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Frontend Quotes.js

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Quotes = async () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  const getQuote = await axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000", {
      crossdomain: true,
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .then((data) => {
      setText({
        data: data,
      });
      console.log("res: ", text);
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getQuote}>Generate Quote</button>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <h3>{author}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quotes;
```

Process:
When I run my process the front execute and call Quotes.js in the axios get process.
app.js then route to home ('/') and call getCase via the app.get.
The getCase process execute get the API token and add it in the headers Authorization. The process initiate the call and fetch the data (if I console.log(res.data.fields.phone) or console.log(res.data.id) I see the correct data.
In my Quotes.js I want to display the data but res.data is empty, yet I get back status 200.

I've been trying to understand why it is not passing the data from the backend to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems and some improvements to be made.

#### Backend

##### Problem - You are sending the entire `AxiosResponse` in the response from your Express app

Just send the data

```js
const getCase = async () =>
  (
    await axios.get(
      "https://5156735-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl",
      {
        params: {
          script: 860,
          deploy: 1,
          recordtype: "supportcase",
          id: 717986,
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${(await getToken()).data.access_token}`,
        },
      }
    )
  ).data; // Return the data, not the whole response
```

##### Problem - getCase() is async

You need to await the result

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.json(await getCase());
  } catch (err) {
    next(err); // send the error to the Express error handler
  }
});
```

##### Improvement - Creating your own CORS middleware is a waste of time

By the time you create a comprehensive CORS middleware, it will look exactly the same as the [standard one](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) so just use that

```js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
express.use(cors());
```

#### Frontend

##### Problem - React function components cannot be async

Function components must return a valid JSX node. Remove `async` from `Quotes`

##### Problem - getQuote should be a function

In order to trigger `getQuote` by button click, it needs to be a function

```jsx
// if text is an object, initialise it as one
const [text, setText] = useState({});

const getQuotes = async () => {
  try {
    // there is no "crossdomain" Axios option
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000");

    setText({ data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
  }
};
```

##### Problem - the text state is an object

JSX cannot render plain objects, you instead need to reference properties that can be rendered.

```jsx
<h1>{text.data?.some?.property}</h1>
```

No idea what your response object looks like so this is just generic advice

Comment: Thank you Phil for your response, I implemented your suggestions and it is now returning the data to the frontend.

Comment: When I reload the page I get the following errors: Quotes.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phone') at Quotes (Quotes.js:24:1) at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1) at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1) at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)... I need to comment out my h1 and h3 save reload and un-comment for it to work

Comment: @Hendrik sounds like you're accessing properties unsafely. I can't really help further without knowing what structure the response takes and what properties you want out of it

Answer (score -1):

The reason why this is not working is for two reasons. Firstly, `res.data` is not an asynchronous function. And since you are doing await, you can just get data. Secondly, you need to make your API calls and setState in the `useEffect` hook or else it would just end up in an infinite rerender situation. You just have to do the following and it should work:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000', {
        crossdomain: true
      })
     setText(data)
  }
  fetchData()
}, [])
```